# Encoding special characters to their hex codes

Tags: java, encoding

I have a following input string: `1%2fPJJP`
I want to convert it to the following: `1&#x25;2fPJJP`

The hexadecimal code for `%` can be found here: http://character-code.com/

How do I do it in Java?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = null;
        try {
            test = URLEncoder.encode("1%2fPJJP", "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

But I got the following: 1%252fPJJP.

How do I do it?

Comment: Is that a known conversion?

Comment: The hexadecimal code for % can be found here: http://character-code.com/

Comment: I suppose you could just do `str.replace("%", "&#x25;")` but why do you want to do this? `%` is a perfectly legal character in both XML and HTML; it doesn't need to be escaped like this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: (In a URL, on the other hand, character entities would not have any meaning. In the query portion of a URL the `&` and `;` would separate key=value pairs; after the path but before the query, the `;` would separate segments of parameters, so I don't think you'd want to put this in a URL.)